# Why can't I type in my fields?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using redux-form and I cannot type inside of my inputs after I add the `initialize` method and `componentDidUpdate()`. When I try to type in my email no characters appear. I am guessing all the inputs become controlled? If so how would I handle that?

```
import { reduxForm, Field, initialize } from 'redux-form';

const CustomComponent = function(field) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <input { ...field.input } type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} />
                </div>
            );
        }

//class instantiation

componentDidUpdate(){
    this.handleInitialize();
}

handleInitialize() {
    const initData = {
       "name": this.props.name
    };
    this.props.initialize(initData);
}



render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <Field name="name" component={CustomComponent} type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                    <Field name="email" component={CustomComponent} type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you try to return input without div wrapper in CustomComponent?

Comment: That does not work. Same issue

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald the answer to that question you posted does not apply because I have already implemented that prior to posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define your `CustomComponent` inside the `render()` method. That will cause your component to lose focus when you first start typing into an input.

Have you set up the reducer properly in your Redux config?

Comment: I moved CustomComponent to outside of my class, but I still cannot type inside of my fields.

Comment: I logged inside of my componentDidUpdate and realized that it is being called every time I attempt to type something in the fields. I'm pretty sure this is the issue.